# Cannot connect to a MSSQL Express 2014 Database using VS 2013 Professional (specifically VB)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2014-express

I read another article concerning this problem when getting the file in use message.  I went into SQL Management studio and disconnected the database but still no success in connecting.  Here's what's happening step by step:

I downloaded SQL Express 2014 and installed it.  I created a DB called MyEntertainmentDB, then created a couple of files (Movies and Rating).  I added some data to both.  I fired up VS and in VB I created a form added various controls including a datagrid.  The DB exists in the default location used by MS SQL.  I clicked the Smart Tag and the data grid view tasks window appears.  I click the choose data source drop down arrow and then add project data source.  Database is highlighted and I click next.  Dataset is highlighted and I click next.  Now I click new connection and select Microsoft SQL Server Database File (Data provider is .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server (the only thing in that drop down box)) and I click Continue.  Now I'm shown a window that has the data source as Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient) in the first box and I browse to where my database is located and select it (which is C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\MyEntertainmentDB.mdf).  Everything is going well and I'm using Windows Authentication.  I click ok.  Now it waits several minutes and I get this message:

The attempt to attach to the database failed with the following message: A network related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.  The server was not found or was not accessible.  Verify the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.  (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.  Cannot create an automatic instance.  See the Windows Application event log for error details.

I looked in theSQL Server log but nothing was mentioned shedding any light.  I could not find any VS log.  I checked the windows logs but could not find anything seemingly relevant.  I'm at a loss for this problem and am about ready to trash MS SQL server and just go with MS Access 2010 or MySQL.  Does anybody see where I'm going wrong?  If so, please help, I've tried to be very specific and hope I've provided all info necessary.

Comment: Please include the connection string you are using, and how you are connecting (ie. a re-create).

Comment: I'm entering all the above info in the VS data connection wizard.  I've supplied all the info I'm using to connect.  If I'm misunderstanding please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must configure your MSSQL Express Server to respond.
To do that you must open SQL Server Configuration Manager (on Windows 8.1 just go in the upper right corner, hit Search and type: SQL Server Configuration Manager. If you are using Windows 7 you can find it on Start Menu).

On SQL Config Manager you must go to expand SQL Server Network Configuration and you'll see Protocols for (your DB instance). Click on that.

After you click on Protocols for (your DB instance) in the right window you will see Shared Memory, Named Pipes and TCP/IP. Double click on each and set them to Enabled = Yes.

Now your MSSQL Server must listen to standard port 1433. To do this double click on TCP/IP, select IP Addresses (Now you will see IP1 config, IP2 config, etc), scroll down to IPAll and set TCP Dynamic Ports to 0 and TCP Port to 1433.

Now restart your SQL Server Service. If don't know how to this, just reboot your computer. After reboot open command prompt and type netstat -a to see if your MSSQL is listening on port 1433.

Now in Visual Studio when you are connecting to your SQL Server on Server Name type server IP (your IP or 127.0.0.1) or you can select your SQL Server instance from dropdown list without any problems.

You can check this tutorial too: [Allow SQL Server Express to accept remote connections](http://support.webecs.com/kb/a868/how-do-i-configure-sql-server-express-to-allow-remote-tcp-ip-connections-on-port-1433.aspx)

Comment: I haven't checked out the tutorial as yet and I thank you for the excellent help you've provided as it cleared a lot of ground so I could see the layout of the land.  You know I've been in MIS for a long time (mostly on bigger machines like IBM 360/370/AS400/S36-38) and decided to try to move into a new arena like OOP and developing applications using these tools. Error now: Unable to add data connection...The system cannot find the file specified.  It works with test connection though.

Comment: Now my error message is Unable to add data connection.  Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version 11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Is clear for me that you have a problem with your SQL Server instalation. My recommandation is MSSQL Server 2014 Express with Advanced Services (first uninstall your current MSSQL and don't forget to configure it again after reinstalation) (Here you can download: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299). Now you must try to install SharedManagementObjects.msi (Here is your link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295). You must download for your architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I finally solved the problem and not in a way people would think.  First off, I want to thank everyone who responded with the intelligent answers, but we were off base on this one and I'm not sure why, but your responses ultimately led to my defeating this problem.  I've been wrestling with this problem for the last 3 days almost exclusively - I don't like being beaten - and 1 entire night. I've uninstalled and re-installed several times and even got superstitious and waved a chicken bone - lol - at it but nothing worked!  I've asked this question on several web sites and finally I went to a link that stated the .msi file was included with MS SQL Server 2012 Management objects I and was hesitant to download as they pertained to the 2012 version. So after tinkering to no avail I downloaded the 2012 CLR Types and Management Objects and looked in the Windows\assemblies folder and still no v 11.  But I guess 2012 installation installed them in Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll v11.0.2100.60.  I ran VS 2013 and added the data source.  After going through all this problem I'm wondering why Microsoft invents all these places to put things when one would work.  Every version of windows from 3 to present has always been totally revised and I wonder for what.  Improvements are okay but quit reinventing the wheel.  Without your help I might not have ever found the solution and perhaps would have been an oracle or mysql guru or not.  Your the men. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Do **not** connect to mdf, connect to the SQL Server and use MyEntertainmentDB database from there.

The MDF file is locked by the SQL Server for reading/writing data.

Comment: This doesn't help either.  I right click on data connections and click add connection and a window appears with data source as: Microsoft SQL Server (SqlClient).  In the next text box Server Name it is blank with my computer name listed in the drop down.  I select this/enter sqlexpress and with each I get the message:  ...The server was not found or was not accessible....

Comment: I should add that the server does not appear in the server explorer.

Comment: Servername should be only your PC name, do not append /SQLExpress or anything. If there are no entries in the "Select or enter a dabase name" dropdown then it looks like as there are some missing/wrongs settings on the sql server